# Posso atribuir valor dentro de um parametro?

Tags: funções, pseudocódigo

Tenho um trabalho em pseudocódigo, em que precisava criar uma função para receber um valor do usuário e fazer o mod por 2, então fiz assim:

```
Função Módulo (x,b=2: inteiro) : inteiro

Var
   i:inteiro
Inicio
 Escreva("Digite um número:")
 Leia (x)
 i=x mod b
 Escreva("O módulo de "+x+" é "+i)
Fim_função"
```

Eu posso adicionar o valor 2 a variável b dentro do parâmetro?

Comment: Pode sim, isso vai deixar a variável com um valor default caso você chame essa função e não informe o segundo parâmetro, ela vai utilizar o valor setado como default.

Answer (score 0):

Depende da linguagem, como é pseudo-código, vai depender do seu professor se vai aceitar ou não.

Isso se chama "parâmetro pré-definido" (ou qualquer coisa que tenha o mesmo significado).

De modo geral, o recurso funciona atribuindo o valor definido na assinatura do método caso não haja argumento correspondente àquele parâmetro.

O fato é que muitas linguagens aceitam isso e algumas (tipo o JavaScript) têm se adaptado pra que isso funcione.

Um exemplo bem simples em JS.

```js
function modulo(x, mod = 2) {
  return x % mod;
}

console.log(modulo(5));    // Aqui, vai fazer mod 2, pq não tem segundo argumento
console.log(modulo(8, 3)); // Aqui, vai fazer mod 3
```